# "Late for bingo" or "late to bingo"?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

I'm interested in getting a custom license plate, but I'm not exactly sure which is correct and/or makes the most sense. The license plate would imply that I am running late for/to bingo, however I can see how it can be perceived as either a noun (an event) or as an verb (the act of playing bingo). It's similar to the word 'work'. With that being said, is it "late for bingo" or "late to bingo?"

Comment: What do you know about the use of "for" and "to"? Have you looked at the existing questions covering their use?

Comment: What's the connection between bingo and a license plate?

Comment: I suspect that the people who voted to close this question were influenced by the OP's motivation for asking the question. If one ignores that motivation, one will, however, be left with a question that is reasonably clear and within the scope of this site.

Comment: We usually use _late for_ when referring to an event with a fixed start time.

Answer (score 2):

> is it "late for bingo" or "late to bingo?"

1. "It was 22:30 when I arrived at the hall and the bingo had finished at 22:00. So  I realised I had come late **for** bingo."
2. "People usually take to playing bingo in their 50s. I had no interest in bingo until I was 70 but now play twice a week - I came late **to** bingo."

It seems that you need 1.

Comment: Excellent distinction.

Comment: OK, but what about the scenario in which one arrives after the time that is announced as the staring time, but still not so late as to miss the game altogether?

Comment: @jsw29 in that case, you have not missed it. "I realised I had come late for *the start of* bingo."